# 404 /index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: maven, jsf, war

I am aware that there are similar questions related to this topic. However, none of the answers did help me and I simply can't get my Intellij/Tomcat running correctly.

Tomcat is not able to find any *.xhtml or plain html file. Every single time I try to run the project out of IntellIj I just get the error mentioned in the title. I also tried deploying the project with maven. Didn't work out well (same problem).

I installed Tomcat with Xampp in the default location C:\xampp on a Win10 64 bit machine. Here is how my project is structured:

[image]

I defined all my dependencies in the pom.xml plus the plugin to deploy the web app on tomcat:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mojarra JSF -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

What i configured for Tomcat in Intellij: [Run/Debug settings in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28c0s.png)

I no longer have any idea whatsoever what this could be. Checked URLs multiple times, threw away that declaration for the virtual /faces/* folder in the web.xml. Here's my full web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener id="ServiceLocator">
        <display-name>InitializeContextListener</display-name>
        <listener-class>wuhu.webclient.InitializeContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>WUHU_SERVICE_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:%s/wuhuservice</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>WUHU_SERVICE_PORT</param-name>
        <param-value>8123</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Looks like your project isn't organized as maven project. Within `src`, the default folder `main` is missing. For a web project, there has to be a folder named `webapp` within `main`. Or did you specify non-default settings in `pom.xml`?

Comment: no. i have to admit i am pretty new to jsf / maven. i will fix this asap

Comment: @tilt32: it is not jsf/maven in this case but 'war'/maven. And by what you state in the title, you suggest it does work using plain maven and not intellij or with a different servlet engine.

Comment: ok i did reorganize the project accordingly to the maven default for webapps and it works now. thank you very much jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faulty Maven project structure, answered by JimHawkins in the comments